# Add alpha for all variants in MUI Theme - React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI theme setup and I would like to add an alpha color to MuiChip. I am not sure on how to access the specific color inside createTheme. For example, if my primaryColor is '#FF0000' and the secondary color is '#00ff00', just for MuiChip, I want to do backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette, 0.1); If I pass a variant prop for the chip component, the backgroundColor should be changed to the alpha version of that variant.

```
    export const theme = createTheme({
      palette: {
        primary: {
          main: colors.primary,
        },
        secondary: {
          main: colors.secondary,
        },
        error: {
          main: colors.red,
        },
      },
      components: {
        
        MuiChip: {
          styleOverrides: {
            colorPrimary: {
              color: 'white',
            },
            root: {
                backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette, 0.1)
            }
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `theme` you misunderstood how MUI works with themes. I see this main problems:

- If you use just MUI `colors.primary` is not valid. You must use exact color code like `#fff`. (not true if you use some kind of `color` lib)
- in `styleOverrides` you must use the template from the doc [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#overrides-based-on-props). With this you will get `theme` and `ownerState` to manipulate components on CSS level.
- `theme.palette` is not the exact color reference you should use `theme.palette.primary.main` in `alpha()`
- You can use `alpha` but I think `opacity` is easier
- Just for information for other readers here we can find [CSS reference of Chip component](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/chip/#css) for Rule Names to override.

I made a working code on [Codesandbox, you can try it](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-agnesi-8ei3ub?file=/src/App.js:739-765).

Here is my theme to solve the problem:

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#a0a"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#0a0"
    },
    error: {
      main: "#a00"
    }
  },
  components: {
    MuiChip: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: "#0a0"
        },
        colorSuccess: ({ ownerState, theme }) => ({
          ...(ownerState.variant === "custom" && {
            backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.3)
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```